# btree for neo4j (java accessible)?

Tags: neo4j

I'm been looking for an neo4j implementation of a btree (accessible from java).

So far all I've come across is
http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.2/xref/org/neo4j/index/impl/btree/BTree.html
which appear to be unreleased code connected to neo4j (it includes the comment 
"This class isn't ready for general usage yet and use of it is discouraged.")

Does anyone know if there is a released version of this?  Or of any other usable version of a btree?

I need a reasonably efficient way of selecting nodes that have a numeric property value in an interval. It doesn't have to be a btree, but that's the standard way to do this sort of thing.

thanks

Comment: If my answer below is of any help, it would be cool to mark it as valid response. :-)
Regarding your second question (numerical range queries), would you mind putting it into a separate question? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There's a BTree implementation in the graph-collections repo, see https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graph-collections/tree/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/collections/btree.

The maven repo location is: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/tree/master/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-collections/0.7.3-neo4j-2.0.3

Usage instructions: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/m2/blob/master/README.md